# the question of 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, shapes

I tried to use this code (https://github.com/phillipiv/rssi-filtering-kalman) to test Kalman filtering, but encountered some issues.

After I ran it, it displayed this error.

How can I fix it?

Give me some advice please.

(I tried to change `lenght = np.shape(signals)[1]` to `lenght = np.shape(np.array(signals))[1]`, and the `AttributeError` disappeared, but `ValueError` still exists.)

```
  File "C:\Users\fan\rssi-filtering-kalman\venv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2033, in shape
    result = a.shape
             ^^^^^^^
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fan\rssi-filtering-kalman\scripts\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    plot_signals([signal, signal_gray_filter, signal_fft_filter, signal_kalman_filter, signal_particle_filter],
  File "C:\Users\fan\rssi-filtering-kalman\scripts\util.py", line 22, in plot_signals
    lenght = np.shape(signals)[1]             # time lenght of original and filtered signals
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in shape
  File "C:\Users\fan\rssi-filtering-kalman\venv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2035, in shape
    result = asarray(a).shape
             ^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (5, 199) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Comment: `signals` is not a numpy array, thus `np.shape` will not work on it. You will need to cast it into a numpy array using `signals = np.array(signals)` before using `np.shape`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have corrected this, but ValueError still exists, what's going on with this?

Comment: @cloud what is the new ValueError? If it is very different you should post a new question

Comment: There are 2 possibilities for `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. First is it's a jagged array (non-uniform lengths) or there are incompatible types involved (float with string).

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your `a` to a numpy array.

`a` is a list.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3]
try:
    a.shape # doesn't work
except AttributeError:
    print("No .shape attribute")

a = np.array(a)

# try
a.shape  # works
```